I can't return(get) the "Authorization" header in the front/ The Authorization field returns undefined - React - Redux -
When logging into my application, the Authorization inside the header returns as undefined
enter image description here
But, when checking within the developer tools in 'Network' the token is there in the Authorization field of the Header
enter image description here
Does anyone know what can it be? I made several changes, such as using only redux later in conjunction with axios, but without success.
My store.js
import { AuthReducer } from "../Auth/Reducer";
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import logger from "redux-logger";

const rootReducers = combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer,
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducers,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger),
});

My action.js
import axios from "axios";

const ROOT_URL = "http://localhost:8080";

export const signinAction = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/signin`, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(data.email + ":" + data.password),
      },
    });

    if (response.status === 200) {
      const authorizationHeader = response.headers.authorization;
      console.log(authorizationHeader);
    } else {
      throw new Error("Falha ao fazer login");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erro:", error.message);
  }
};

My Reducer.js
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_UP } from "./ActionType";

const initialValue = {
  signup: null,
  signin: null,
};
export const AuthReducer = (store = initialValue, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === SIGN_IN) {
    return { ...store, signin: payload };
  } else if (type === SIGN_UP) {
    return { ...store, signup: payload };
  }
  return store;
};

My dispatch in Signin.jsx
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleSubmit = (values, actions) => {
    dispatch(signinAction(values));
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
  };

My CORS configuration
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String originHeader = request.getHeader("origin");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3000");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())){
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

My call sigin in Backend
@GetMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity<User> signInHandler(Authentication auth) throws BadCredentialsException {
    Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByEmail(auth.getName());

    if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(optionalUser.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
}

And I hope I can get the Authorization value

I solved this problem by adding
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");

in the CORS doFilter method


@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        String originHeader = request.getHeader("origin");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3000");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");


        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())){
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }



